# ModelCheckpoint not saving checkpoint files (.h5 files)

Tags: keras, nlp, tf.keras

```
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
adadelta = tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr=0.9, rho=0.95, epsilon=None, decay=0.002)
lr_metric = get_lr_metric(adadelta)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adadelta, metrics=['acc'])

path = "D:/Jupyter Notebooks/Text-Emotion-Analysis/Text-Emotion-Analysis-master/checkpoints/checkpoint-{val_acc:.4f}.h5"

tensorboard = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=0, batch_size=16, write_grads=True , write_graph=True)
model_checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint(path,monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=0)
lr_schedule = callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(initial_boost)
```

When I run the code shown above, there are no checkpoints that get saved onto my checkpoints folder.

Does anyone know the reason as to why?

Comment: Are you passing the callbacks list to your `model.fit()` method?
`callbacks = [tensorboard, model_checkpoints, lr_schedule] >> 
model.fit(dataset, callbacks=callbacks)`

Comment: Yes I am, I did that already, what I simply dont understand is why there are no checkpoints saved for this line only "model_checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint(path,monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=0)"


Is that not whats supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late for your help, but still might help people searching for answer.

I realized that this is a bug in `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`. When you try to give path with `"drive_letter:/" or "./" or "/"` it fails to access the folder and save checkpoint weights. When I enter the path without any forward slash or leeter in the beginning, it works.

For Example:

1. `checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint('./checkpoints/epoch_{epoch:02d}_loss{val_loss:.3f}.h5')` = Fails
2. `checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint('/checkpoints/epoch_{epoch:02d}_loss{val_loss:.3f}.h5')` = Fails

but

`checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint('checkpoints/epoch_{epoch:02d}_loss{val_loss:.3f}.h5')` = Works

So whenever giving path for `ModelCheckpoint` do not include any slashes in the beginning.

I hope this helps everyone getting frustrated over keras not saving checkpoints